# Airflow - Pass UTC timestamp as variable

Tags: datetime, airflow

In one of my airflow task, I want to pass the current Month current hour and last hour(in UTC) as a variable.

I know macros are there, but the airflow is running with IST timestamp, how can I get the variable data in UTC? any sample code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`execution_date` is Pendulum object so you can use `in_tz()`

```
{{ execution_date.in_tz('UTC') }}
```

you can then format the pattern and extract the str as you need.
For example to get the month:

```
op = BashOperator(
    task_id="example",
    bash_command="echo the month extracted from {{ execution_date.in_tz('UTC') }}"  \
                 " is {{ execution_date.in_tz('UTC').strftime('%m') }}"
)
```

[image]